# Krull dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

I have the following exercise:

Consider the rings $A:=\mathbb{C}[x,y,w,z]/(xw-yz)$ and $B:=A/(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$.

*(i)* Calculate the Krull dimensions of $A$ and $B$.

*(ii)* Consider the prime ideal $P=(\bar{w}, \bar{z})\subset A$ and let $Q$ be its image in $B$. Calculate the height of $P$ and the height of $Q$.

---

> *(i)*
>
> - **Dimension of A**
>
> I know that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,w,z]$ has Krull dimension$=4$, because $\mathbb{C}$ is a field. So I expect dim$A<4$ (upper bound).
>
> The first problem is that $A$ is a integral domain...so can I be sure that dim$A<4$ and not dim$A\leq 4$?
> I think no: if $A$ had been a integral domain, a chain in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,w,z]$ could always have extended to a chain in $A$ by addition of $(0)$.
>
> However, if really dim$A<4$, I would like to find a chain of prime ideals of $A$ with lenght 3. In this case a prime ideal of A has height$=3$ and by definition of Krull dimension, dim$A\geq3$ (lower bound) so I can conclude dim$A=3$. (Though this is just a supposition, I'm not really sure that dim$A=3$). But I can't find the ideals that form the chain!
>
> - **Dimension of B**
>
> Because of $(0)\subset(\bar{x})\subset(\bar{x,}\bar{y})$, can I immediately conclude dim$B=2$? I'm not sure...Can dim$B$ not depend on dim$A$?

> *(ii)*
>
> - **Height of P**
>
> $A$ is a integral domain, so we have $(0)\subset(\bar{w})\subset(\bar{w},\bar{z})=P$ and height of $P$ is 2, isn't it?
>
> - **Height of Q**
>
> I don't know how to calculate its height. Perhaps because $B$ is obtained by quoting $A$ with $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$, instead $P$ is generated by the two remaining $\bar{z},\bar{w}$,its image in $B$ has the same height.

If you can help me, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sure I saw this very question quite recently....

Comment: @AnginaSeng this user posted a version of it yesterday, got a couple comments telling them to improve their question, deleted it, and then posted this version today.

Comment: In the future, please do not delete and repost, instead use the [edit] feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a theorem to the effect that if $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a non-zero polynomial over a field $K$ then $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ has Krull dimension $n-1$.
It's a special case of the theorem that if $R=K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$ for some
ideal $I$, then the Krull dimension of $R$ is the transcendence degree of the
field of fractions of $R$ over $K$.

To find a chain of prime ideals in $R=K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$
think geometrically and find a solution $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=0$
and consider the chain $(0)\subseteq(X_1-a_1)\subseteq(X_1-a_1,X_1-a_2)\subseteq\cdots
\subseteq(X_1-a_1,X_1-a_2,\ldots,X_{n-1}-a_{n-1})$. If you choose $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$
carefully this will be a suitable chain of prime ideals.

Note that
$$B\cong\frac{\Bbb C[x,y,w,z]}{(x,y,xw-yz)}.$$
There is a convenient alternative way to write the ideal $(x,y,xw-yz)$ which makes
the structure of $B$ more evident.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for any domain $R$ that is a finitely generated algebra over a field and any ideal $I$ of $R,$ we have that $$\operatorname{height} I + \dim(R / I) = \dim R.$$ Every polynomial ring in finitely many indeterminates over a field $k$ is a domain and a finitely generated $k$-algebra, hence this equation holds. By Krull's Height Theorem, we have that $\operatorname{height} I = \operatorname{height}(wx - yz) \leq 1.$ But $I$ is a nonzero prime ideal of $\mathbb C[w, x, y, z],$ hence we have that $\operatorname{height} I = 1.$ Consequently, we have that $$\dim(\mathbb C[w, x, y, z] / (wx - yz)) = \dim \mathbb C[w, x, y, z]  - \operatorname{height} I = 4 - \operatorname{height} I = 3.$$ Observe that a maximal chain of prime ideals in $\mathbb C[w, x, y, z] / (wx - yz)$ is given by $$(\bar 0) = (\overline{wx - yz}) = (\bar w \bar x - \bar y \bar z) \subsetneq (\bar x, \bar y) \subsetneq (\bar x, \bar y, \bar z) \subsetneq (\bar w, \bar x, \bar y, \bar z).$$

By the Third Isomorphism Theorem, we have that $B \cong \mathbb C[w, x, y, z] / (x, y).$ Once again, we have that $\operatorname{height} (x, y) \leq 2,$ and we have a maximal chain of prime ideals $(0) \subsetneq (x) \subsetneq (x, y),$ from which it follows that $\dim B = \dim \mathbb C[w, x, y, z] - 2 = 4 - 2 = 2$ with a maximal chain of prime ideals $(\bar 0) \subsetneq (\bar x) \subsetneq (\bar x, \bar y).$

For the ideal $P = (\bar w, \bar z)$ of $A,$ you are correct that the height is $2,$ as evidenced by your maximal chain of prime ideals. For the ideal $Q,$ observe that by our above isomorphism, we have that $Q = (\bar w, \bar z)$ in $\mathbb C[w, x, y, z] / (x, y) \cong \mathbb C[w, z],$ hence $Q$ is maximal, and its height is $\dim \mathbb C[w, z] = 2.$

Comment: Are you sure that your first line is true as stated? Most references that I can think of require that $R$ be a domain as well.

Comment: It is certainly true if $R$ is a domain, and that is the case we are dealing with here. If you can think of a counterexample when $R$ is not a domain, I would be interested in seeing it; however, I am not aware of one. I think this is just one of those “folklore” theorems.

Comment: First, a counterexample in the case that $R$ is not a domain is immediate: in $k[x,y]/(xy)$, the ideal $(x)$ is of height one and the quotient, $k[y]$, is of dimension one, but $k[x,y]/(xy)$ is Krull dimension one, and $1+1\neq 1$. Second, this theorem is not folklore. One may reference Matsumura Chapter 5 Section 14, or Atiyah-MacDonald Chapter 11 (when $k$ is algebraically closed).

Comment: Indeed, as @KReiser kindly points out, this is not true. Another nice example is given by $R = \mathbb{C}[X, Y, Z]/\langle XY, XZ \rangle$. The maximal ideals $M_{1} = \langle X-1, Y, Z \rangle$ and $M_{2} = \langle X, Y-1, Z \rangle$ have heights $1$ and $2$ respectively, which therefore gives a counterexample: see #4 of https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2017/hs/401-3132-00L/ex/Sol9.pdf. (I haven't checked the details carefully, but it looks alright to me.)

Comment: @KReiser, you misunderstand: the theorem in the case that $R$ is a domain is well-known, as you point out (e.g., I read it in *Twenty-Four Hours of Local Cohomology* by Iyengar, et al.). But your counterexample is correct. I was (incorrectly) assured that the result held in greater generality, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: @KReiser: actually, now I am a bit confused. I think that $\langle X \rangle$ is a minimal prime of $k[X, Y]/\langle XY \rangle$, and so should have height $0$. (Indeed, we always must have $ht(P) + dim(A/P) \leqslant dim(A)$, right?) Anyway, not so important, as there are indeed counterexamples...

Comment: @AlexWertheim You're correct, I was hasty and wrong when I wrote that (I'll blame the lateness of the hour, too, maybe?). Anyways, the point about the result being false if $R$ isn't a domain is the important part, and this is ably demonstrated by your counterexample.